# Solving intermittent Garbage Collection problem - Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, live

I have spring enterprise app running on JDK 1.6 under Windows 2008. The app gets slow or unresponsive at random times. I suspect it is memory leak and the GC is kicking into over drive.

How can I troubleshoot this without restarting JVM using java.exe -verbose:gc parameter? I really cannot shutdown this app. I'm planning on doing AppDynamics on it once I can restart it but for know what can I do? What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the application and run jconsole on the PID.  While its running look at the heap in the console.  When it near maxes get a heap dump.  Download Eclipse MAT and parse the heap dump.  If you notice the retained heap size is vastly less then the actual binary file parse the heap dump with -keep_unreachable_objects being set.

If the latter is true and you are doing a full GC often you probably have some kind of leak going on.  Keep in mind when I say leak I don't mean a leak where the GC cannot retain memory, rather some how you are building large objects and making them unreachable often enough to cause the GC to consume a lot of CPU time.

If you were seeing true memory leaks you would see GC Over head reached errors

Comment: @Mat Banik There isnt a clear way of getting the PID right.  I usually just start up the app and watch which new java.exe has started.  Also the one with the most virtual memory usually points to where I am looking in a situation like this